# How to upgrade ionic 3 source to ionic 5 directly?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic5

I have been working on Ionic 3 project for almost 2 years and now worrying about the upgrade to Ionic 5 or 6 which have n number of feature and code logic updates (especially routing), so please let me know how to convert from Ionic3 to 5 or 6 without creating a new project from scratch.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will not find this solution direct. I will guide you how you can achieve it. For Ionic 5,6 you will need newer node version. So NVM will take care of it.

[https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/using-nvm/#:~:text=With%20nvm%20you%20can%20install,installed%20for%20different%20node%20versions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/using-nvm/#:%7E:text=With%20nvm%20you%20can%20install,installed%20for%20different%20node%20versions).

Here you will get nvm installation guide.

What you'll do is let nvm take control of existing node version and install a newer as well. So using nvm use 12.19.0 example will put system in new node environment where you'll install ionic and cordova latest version.

If you want to use old ionic than nvm use oldversion and than normally use old commands. Remember newer won't support old node and lower won't support new

Once you have this setup. For each component say example home from ionic 3
you will need to create a new home page component on ionic 5/6. And than copy html,ts,scss files from ionic 3 to 5/6. If something breaks you need to do a short research. And that's how you will have to do it.

For providers in 3 you ll be having services in new ionic version and copy functions in it. Remember you cannot copy paste entire page but things like functions , constructor.